# How do I install a WiFi thermostat with a Well-McLain steam boiler?

Tags: electrical, wiring, heating, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire

I have a [Weil-Mclain](http://www.weil-mclain.com/en/weil-mclain/pd-brazed-plate-heat-exchangers/) 150000 BTU steam boiler, and have only 2 wires connected to my thermostat, but would like to add a new Honeywell WiFi thermostat. I have no C wire, no A/C, or any other type of heating system in my home besides a water boiler.

Is it possible to install this thermostat and how?

Comment: How many wires are in the cable at the thermostat? Have you contacted Honeywell support? Do you have the schematic for the boiler?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - but you will need to run a new thermostat wire.  With your setup, the thermostat wire you run will need three conductors.  However, consider installing one with five conductors or more for a few extra dollars - helping to future-proof your wiring.

Old 'two-wire' thermostats worked like a switch.  The house got cold, the thermostat made a connection, 24VAC was sent to the boiler until the warm house broke the connection.

Your new thermostat needs constant 24VAC (that's where the C wire comes in) as supplied by your transformer, and uses the third wire to communicate with the boiler heating relay. Thermostat uses the 24VAC to operate, and when there is a call for heat, it sends a 24VAC signal to the boiler.